# "start from the beginning" vs "begin from the starting"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, nouns, word-order, gerunds

What is the difference between the following two sentences? Do they both mean the same?

> Why don't you start from the beginning?
>
> Why don't you begin from the starting?

Comment: One is a common idiom: "start from the beginning". The other is never heard, for complex reasons the answerers explain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first sentence is fine. Your second sentence is not.

*Begin* and *start* are both verbs, so  they can be interchanged.

The equivalent noun of *begin* is *beginning*.

The equivalent noun of *start* is *start*

(*Beginning* and *start* are synonyms and can be interchanged.)

So your second sentence should be:

> Why don't you begin from the start?

That is, *beginning* and *start* are both "regular" or autonomous nouns. They function the same. They have their own dictionary entry *as nouns*. The fact that *beginning* ends in *-ing* just indicates a different formation. Compare: *building*. No one doubts that *building* is a noun!

(Nouns such as *[beginning](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beginning&allowed_in_frame=0)* and *[building](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=building)* were evidently made from the verb + -ing **centuries ago**, but they long since began to be autonomous nouns with all the features of other nouns, such as *start* (for example, they have plural forms (*beginnings, buildings, starts*) and they are modified by adjectives. They have their own dictionary entry as *nouns*.

However, *starting* is a gerund. It is the -ing form of a verb acting as a noun. As such it has properties of a verb, not a noun. For example it can take a direct object, it is modified by an ad*verb*. It is not a permanent or autonomous noun. Look up *starting* up in a dictionary: it will redirect you to the verb *start*. (At least the six  dictionaries I tried did this.) This indicates that *starting* is not considered an autonomous noun (rather, *start* is).

We don't say *Begin at the starting.* We say *Begin at the starting point* Thus we use *starting* as an adjective. It is also a gerund, as in "Starting the race from the beginning is a good idea." Notice that *starting* can have a direct object, when it is a gerund.

Now, to slightly complicate matters, since both *begin* and *build* are verbs, they can also be used as gerunds: *beginning* and *building*. But these words as gerunds can be thought of as different words from the autonomous nouns *beginning* and *building* (discussed above) As gerunds, they act the same as the gerund *starting*:

*Beginning (gerund) at the beginning (noun), she read all the letters.*

*Building (gerund) a large building (noun) takes time.*

But we just don't say:

- Starting (gerund) at the starting, she read all the letters.

So *starting* works as a gerund, but it is not an actual noun, (or a regular noun, or an autonomous noun, or a noun proper--take your pick of terminology).

One can say

*In/at the beginning (noun), God created...*

but we don't say:

- In/at the starting, God created...

We could say

*In/at the start (noun), God created...*

Comment: I love your answer. I would like to ask why do we have a noun *start* but don't have a noun *build*?

Comment: We do have a noun *build*. In fact, as a noun, *build* can mean more than one thing [return to etymology online and also you can push the little blue book for dictionary definitio](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=build&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: Then why don't we have the *begin* as noun? I mean, in general, why some verbs have their nouns form exactly like them while the others are not?

Comment: @Ooker I don't know the answer. I am not a historical linguist. This would be a wonderful question to ask on ELU. I would like to know also. In general I know that English began to reassert itself by the time of Chaucer (14th century) after being dominated for 300 years by French after the Norman invasion of 1066.

Comment: I have raise [that question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227650/why-some-verbs-have-their-nouns-form-exactly-like-them-while-the-others-are-not). Hope to see you there.

Answer (score 5):

The first sentence is the more common usage, although technically both have the same meaning. The first sentence is a very common phrase, however, to the extent that most people hearing the second would probably assume that it was an intentional "twist" on the more common phrase.

"Start" and "begin" can mostly interchange as verbs, but "starting" is not often used in the same sense as "beginning". Theoretically, they are the same to the extent that they are both gerunds formed from verbs that are near synonyms. However, "starting" is more often used in phrases: "starting up", "starting line", "starting place", "starting point", "at starting". I don't know that there is any theory to explain why; it's probably just the way the usage has developed.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated, "start from the beginning" is a common idiom used as an instruction to describe a series of events in chronological order, from first cause onwards.

Begin from the starting, however, can only make sense if a "starting" is being used a noun, rather than a gerund.

If an engineer is explaining how an electric motor works to his students, an electric motor has two modes: starting, and running. Once you understand the starting, you can understand the running without much additional information, so typically, a teacher will arrange his notes to begin from the starting, and then work on to the continued running.

But while in theory it could be used as a sentence... Google n-grams show this word has almost no use, and searching Google books shows those words used together only when starting is used to modify a subsequent word: starting-point, starting premise, starting condition, starting block.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=start+from+the+beginning%2Cbegin+from+the+starting&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3